# Создать кнопку "удалить" в Джанго

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь сделать кнопку "удалить" на странице менеджера, где расположена таблица. Вместо этого возникают вечные ошибки.

Ошибка:

```
menedger() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
```

Либо, когда я ввожу `.../menedger/` в строку поиска, выводит 404.

urls.py

```
path("menedger/<int:pk>/", view=views.menedger, name="menedger"),
```

views.py

```
def menedger(request, pk):
    anketa = Anketa.objects.all()
    personal = Personal.objects.all()
    answers = AnswerPersonal.objects.all()

    anketa = get_object_or_404(Anketa, pk=pk)
    personal = get_object_or_404(Personal, pk=pk)
    answers = get_object_or_404(AnswerPersonal, pk=pk)
     
    if request.method=='POST':
        anketa.delete()
        personal.delete()
        answers.delete()

    return render(request, 'logistic/menedger.html', {'answers': answers, 'personal': personal, 'anketa': anketa})
```

menedger.py

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>{% block title %}Менеджер{% endblock %}</title>
  <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'logistic/css/style.css' %}">
  <link rel = "stylesheet"  href="{% static 'logistic/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class = "body-menedger">
    <img src = "{% static 'logistic/image/1900/Fotolia_19966678_L_Sapsiwai-1900.jpg' %}"/>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <a href="{% url 'home' %}">
    <div class="home">Главная</div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="text_bd">Таблица Вопросы и Отзывы</div>

<div class = "button_edit_delete">
<button type="submit" id="button_edit">Редактировать</button>
</div>

<div class = "scroll">
    <table class="table_qr" border="2">
    {% for item in answers %}
         <tr class = "tr_qa">
          <form action="{% url 'menedger' answers.id %}" method="post">
                    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.questions }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.reviews }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
                    {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" id="button_delete" value="Delete cat">
          </form>
          
          </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
    </table>   
</div>






<div class = "bd_two">
<div class="text_bd_two">Таблица зарегистрированные пользователи</div>

<div class = "button_edit_delete_two">
  <button type="submit" id="button_edit">Редактировать</button>
  </div>

  <div class = "scroll-two">
  <table class="table_qr" border="2">
  {% for item in personal %}
       <tr class = "tr_qa">
        <form action="{% url 'menedger' personal.id %}" method="post">
          <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.fio }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.username }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.password }}</td>
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="submit" id="button_delete" value="Delete cat">
          </form>
      </tr> 
  {% endfor %}
  </table>   
</div>
</div>


<div class = "bd_free">
  <div class="text_bd_free">Таблица Анкета</div>
  
  <div class = "button_edit_delete_free">
    <button type="submit" id="button_edit">Редактировать</button>
    </div>
  

  <div class = "scroll-free">
    <table class="table_qr" border="2">
    {% for item in anketa %}
         <tr class = "tr_m">
          <form action="{% url 'menedger' anketa.id %}" method="post">
            <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.q1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.q2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.q3 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.q4 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.q5 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.q6 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.q7 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.q8 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.q9 }}</td>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="submit" id="button_delete" value="Delete cat">
          </form>
        </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
    </table>   
  </div>
  </div>



  <a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"><button type="submit" id="button_bd">База данных</button></a>
  <a href="{% url 'button_yandex_metric' %}"><button type="submit" id="button_yandex_metric">Яндекс.Метрика</button></a>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы в адресе формы неверно атрибут передали

```
{% for item in answers %}
     <tr class = "tr_qa">
      <form action="{% url 'menedger' item.id %}" method="post">
                <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.questions }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.reviews }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.date }}</td>
                {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" id="button_delete" value="Delete cat">
      </form>
      
      </tr> 
{% endfor %}
```